# On Galois closure

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I'm working on this problem in Hungerford: For $\sigma \in Aut_F \bar{F}$, show that every finite extension of $K$, the fixed field of $\sigma$, is cyclic.

For a finite extension $L$ of $K$, let $M$ be a Galois closure of $L$ then I can show that $M/K$ is cyclic so $L/K$ is cyclic.. but there is one problem; is $M/K$ is finite? When $F$ has characteristic zero, $L$ is separable over $K$ so simple by primitive element theorem and so $M$ is finite. However, if $F$ has nonzero characteristic, this proof is not applicable. How can I show that $M/K$ is finite?

Comment: + I noticed that the Galois closure is defined on separable extensions only. However, unless $K$ is perfect, $L$ may not be separable. So I think $char(F)=0$ is a necessary condition for this problem.. Am I right?

Comment: What does it mean for a field to be cyclic? That it's Galois, with Galois group cyclic?

Comment: $L/K$ is cyclic if $Aut_K L$ is cyclic.

Comment: According to your definition cyclic extensions are allowed to be inseparable. Thus you should not work with the Galois closure but with the normal closure. The normal closure of a finite extension $K|F$ is finite, since it is the splitting field of the minimal polynomials of a set of generators of $K|F$, and there are finite sets of generators.

Comment: @Hagen But I used Galois correspondence in my solution.. Is there any way to modify the solution with the normal closure?

Comment: Yes, just work over the fixed field $M^\sigma$ of $\sigma$ in the normal closure $M|F$ of $K|F$. The extension $M|M^\sigma$ is Galois, and if you can prove that it is cyclic, then $\mathrm{Aut}_F(K)$ is cyclic, because the purely inseparable part $M^\sigma|F$ does not change the automoorphism group.

Comment: I'll try again. Thanks!

Comment: See here : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152984/galois-groups-of-finite-extensions-of-fixed-fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this setting $L/K$ will always be separable.

To see that let $z\in L\setminus K$ be arbitrary. Because $L/K$ is finite, $z$ is algebraic over $K$. Therefore $z$ has a minimal polynomial $m(x)\in K[x]$. Over $\overline{F}$ $m(x)$ splits into linear factors
$$
m(x)=(x-z_1)(x-z_2)\cdots (x-z_n)
$$
with $z_1=z$. The elements $\sigma^i(z)$, $i=0,1,2,\ldots,$ are all roots of $m(x)$, so they are among the $z_j$:s. In particular there are only finitely many $\sigma^i(z)$:s. Let $k$ be the smallest positive integer such that $\sigma^k(z)$ is among the $\sigma^j(z), 0\le j<k$. Because $\sigma$ is bijective this implies that $\sigma^k(z)=z$.

Next consider the polynomial
$$
f(x)=(x-z)(x-\sigma(z))(x-\sigma^2(z))\cdots (x-\sigma^{k-1}(z)).
$$
Its zeros are all distinct. And we see that the coefficients of $f$ are fixed under $\sigma$. Therefore $f(x)\in K[x]$. This implies that $m(x)$, as the minimal polynomial, is a factor of $f(x)$. That shows that $m(x)$ is separable proving the claim.

We also see that we must have $m(x)=f(x)$. I guess that we could turn that into a solution by-passing your separability concern altogether, but I haven't thought it through.

Comment: Thanks. I know that generally an arbitrary finite extension is not separable; it is true only when $F$ is perfect. Can you explain why this method is not available in an arbitrary base field?

Comment: @Guest: Delighted that you asked! An arbitrary base field is not the fixed field of an automorphism (or a group of automorphisms) of an algebraically closed field. For example, if $K$ is not perfect of and of characteristic $p$, then all the $K$-automorphisms will fix all the elements of $K^{1/p}$ also.