# Having trouble with Hungerford V.7 proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $K$ be a field, $\bar{K}$ an algebraic closure and $\sigma \in \mathrm{Aut}_K \bar{K}$. Let $F=\{u \in \bar{K} \mid \sigma(u)=u\}$. Then prove $F$ is a field and every finite-dimensional extension of $F$ is cyclic.

Comment: Since you may have simply copied an exercise from a book, there is a risk of people down-voting your question or voting to close it for lack of thoughts of your own about it included in the question, indicating perhaps specifically where you got stuck when trying to solve it, or some question of your own about it. $\qquad$

Comment: There are two things to prove.  Did you succeed in proving one of them and fail with the other? Proving $F$ is a field seems fairly easy.  The other part I haven't thought about yet. $\qquad$

Comment: Do you know some Galois theory ? Being fixed by $\sigma$ is the same as being fixed by the subgroup $\langle \sigma\rangle$ it generates.

Comment: [More answers to the same question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1526917/11619). Still looking for a definite duplicate target.

Comment: I deleted my answer because it was for all purposes a duplicate of [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/152984/11619).